# how can I auto-launch electron app on MacOS

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

please let me know a working way to auto-launch an application after installing the "pkg" package on macOS.
I've tried this: http://macinstallers.blogspot.com/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html
its doesnt work. Script doesnt work after installation.

package.json:

```
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "test",
"main": "main.js",
build": {
"mac": {
"target": [
  {
    "target": "pkg",
    "arch": [
      "x64"
    ]
  }
]
},
"pkg": {
"scripts": "./scripts/postinstall.sh"
}
}
```

postinstall.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a test
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a launch agent

1. Create a .plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents with the path to your app executable and desired launch parameters.
2. Set the plist to load on login by running:

   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourcompany.appname.plist

This will launch your app automatically when a user logs in.

Use a postinstall script

The postinstall script approach you tried can work, but the script needs to be executable. To fix:

1. Add postinstall_script.sh to your Electron project
2. Make sure it has a shebang line #!/bin/sh
3. Make it executable with chmod +x postinstall_script.sh
4. Reference it in your package.json:

   "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "./postinstall_script.sh"
   }
5. Script should contain:

   open -a YourApp

Use an install phase script

1. Add a shell script to run your app to resources/installer.scpt
2. Reference it in your .pkg definition:

   resources/installer.scpt

This will launch your app when the install completes.

So in summary, you can auto-launch an Electron app on install using launch agents, postinstall scripts, or install phase scripts in your .pkg. The launch agent approach runs it on login, while the others launch once on install.

Comment: Did like in "Use a postinstall script" but recived error:
- configuration.pkg.scripts should be:
   null | string
   -> The scripts directory, relative to `build` (build resources directory).
   The scripts can be in any language so long as the files are marked executable and have the appropriate shebang indicating the path to the interpreter.
   Scripts are required to be executable (`chmod +x file`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a plist file at ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourcompany.yourapp.plist with this content:

   Label
      com.yourcompany.yourapp

   ProgramArguments

   /Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp

   RunAtLoad
2. Make sure the path to your app executable is correct.
3. Run this to load the agent:

   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourcompany.yourapp.plist

This will now launch YourApp automatically when you login.

The benefit of this approach is it doesn't rely on postinstall scripts in the .pkg, so should be more reliable.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: why did you answer the same question twice?